# Measuring junction temperature of a diode

Tags: simulation

I am using Simetrix for my simulations. I want to measure the junction temperature of a diode. I don't know how to do it. I gone through all the tutorials and enough of googling. But I couldn't get it. Can anyone help?

Comment: You'll need at least three (perhaps four) calibration points to characterize any particular diode for temperature measurement. In addition, you need to specify the repeatable precision, allowable drift over time, any accuracy requirements, and take into account the fact that there are, in principle, at least two different temperature-dependent equations relating diode voltage to temperature (assuming you want to use voltage measurements and assuming you also wish to avoid self-heating due to the applied current by using narrow pulse techniques.) But we need specs, first, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You'd already know your the Maximum Operating Ambient temperature of the diode and Thermal Resistance of the diode from Junction to Ambient.

Add a Power Probe (Tools -> Efficiency Calculator -> Add Power Probes to Schematic) to the Diode

With Power, Ambient temperature and thermal Resistance, you can find the Junction temperature of the diode.